# ASP .NET MVC 4 dependency injection "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, .net-4.8

I am trying to inject `IProfileService` into controller constructor but I am getting error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" when calling that controller. If I add parameterless constructor, controller calls it uses it, but then I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on `_profileService.SetPropertyValues(ctx, values);` as it is null if not injected.

Interface:

```
namespace SecurityGuard.Interfaces
{
    public interface IProfileService
    {
        string ApplicationName { get; set; }

        int DeleteInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate);
        int DeleteProfiles(string[] usernames);
        int DeleteProfiles(ProfileInfoCollection profiles);
        ProfileInfoCollection FindInactiveProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, string usernameToMatch, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
        ProfileInfoCollection FindProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
        ProfileInfoCollection GetAllInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
        ProfileInfoCollection GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
        int GetNumberOfInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate);
        SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection collection);
        void SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class AjaxSelectController : AmrController
    {
        private readonly IProfileService _profileService;

        public AjaxSelectController(IProfileService profileService) {
            _profileService = profileService;
        }
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveTableColumnsToDb(string data, string propertyName)
        {
            try
            {
                _profileService.SetPropertyValues(ctx, values);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you should include configure services, and the classes, interfaces code

Comment: And what's the constructor for the class that actually implements that interface?

Comment: Hi @forrestDumb, would you mind reducing the amount of code in your question to the minimum that allows reproducing the problem? In other words, make your question into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's currently a lot of code to go through, while most of it is likely not related to your problem. Reducing the code, therefore, makes it easier for others to help and improves the chances of you getting quality answers.

Comment: I reduced it, sorry for too long code.

Comment: Check `IProfileService` implementation and its dependencies. That default error message usually means one of the dependencies in the object graph had an issue when resolving that target controller.

Comment: Looks like your implementation for `IProfileService` might be requesting a few dependencies which are not yet registered into DI.

Comment: Any advice on how to trace those dependencies ?